# Buildroot, python-PyQt5 Error when building image

Tags: pyqt5, buildroot, python-sip

I'm Oguzhan. I am new on Embedded Linux and trying to image for my Raspberry Pi 3b.
I tried to compile my new image with PyQt5 package and i took this error:

```
siplib.c: In function ‘sip_api_get_frame’:
siplib.c:13750:22: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct _frame’
13750 |         frame = frame->f_back;
      |                      ^~
```

I did some research about this issue and i found this link:

(https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/commit/?id=3ef6884e6d59744d83649170822a4829eed146fc)

It's looking like solution but i don't have any idea about the solution is this and if yes it is, i don't have any idea about how to patching the buildroot packages.

Could you help me guys? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in upstream Buildroot just a few days ago. It has not yet made its way into a release. You can do one of the following things to fix your issue.

1. Wait until Buildroot 2023.02.8 or 2023.11.1 is released and update to that version.
2. Update Buildroot to current master. If you're using a git clone of Buildroot, that's just a matter of running `git pull`.
3. Apply just this one fix to your local Buildroot version.
   If you're using a git clone of Buildroot, you can do that with

   ```
   git fetch
   git cherry-pick 3ef6884e6d59744d83649170822a4829eed146fc
   ```

   If you don't have a git clone, then you can use

   ```
   curl https://gitlab.com/buildroot.org/buildroot/-/commit/3ef6884e6d59744d83649170822a4829eed146fc.patch \
       | patch -p1
   ```

Comment: Hi @Arnout. Yesterday, I manually applied the code line changes included in this patch one by one and the sip problem at the compilation point was fixed, but this morning I wanted to run my PyQt5 application in the compiled image and I received the error "No module named PyQt5.sip". Now I patched it as you said and i'm recompiling the image. If I get the same error again I will let you know. I am a junior and nobody can help me in my company also i can not find any info about this error on the Internet. Please keep in touch with me Arnout.

Comment: I applied the patch you just mentioned and compiled the image. But when I want to run my PyQt5 application. I keep getting this error: (Next comment)

Comment: # python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/resources/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'

Comment: That's as far as my knowledge goes I'm afraid. You better reach out on the mailing list for help. Perhaps read this thread: https://lore.kernel.org/buildroot/20231212160112.94272-2-hypnotoad@lindra.de/

Comment: I really appreciate your help. When I applied the patch in the link, I started getting a different error. This is also an improvement, but my patience is about to run out :). I will share the current error with the next comment.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/resources/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWidgets' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.pyc)

Comment: Update: Fixed this error too after building image from stracth. Thank you so much again.